# display images in a datatable according to the value of an attribute in tha database JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to display icons with colors (green, orange,red) in a column of a jsf datatable showing the urgency of a chirurgical operations.  depending on an attribute in the database this icon will be displayed.

hwo can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't have much details, but you can simply do something like this using the `rendered` attribute and some state getter/setter on your operation Object.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{yourBean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            Urgency
        </f:facet>

        <h:graphicImage rendered="#{item.state eq 1}" value="images/icon1.png" />
        <h:graphicImage rendered="#{item.state eq 2}" value="images/icon2.png" />
        <h:graphicImage rendered="#{item.state eq 3}" value="images/icon3.png" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```